# function: findnextchar() doesn't work

Tags: c

I have to write a function: `findNextChar()`. The function must have 2 arguments, 1 string and 1 char. The char is a character which have to be found in the string. If the character gets found the next character in the array should get stored in a array and a '\0' should get appended at the end. E.g:

```
Kukuruz" und "u" = 'k','r','z',\0'
```

But in my code only the first character of the string gets found (`'k','k','k','\0'`)

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char string[]="Kukuruz";
  char *search;
  char array[3];
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    search = strchr(string, 'u');
    search++;
    strncpy(array, search, 1);
    printf("'%s',",array);
  }
  printf("'/0'");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use English language at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry but this is an english-only website. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not written in English

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not written in english hence not understandable.

Comment: @SouravGhosh , Beat you by 10.5 seconds! :p

Comment: @CoolGuy yep, enjoy.. :-) Happy new year, BTW.

Comment: translated it. As good as i could.

Comment: @Rizier123: IMO better than the original ;-)

Comment: @Rizier123 removed close vote. What was the original language anyway?

Comment: @SouravGhosh German :D, the only thing is OP wrote the question in german so i'm not sure if he understands english xD, maybe we have to translate the answer from english to german for him

Comment: @SouravGhosh , How does one remove his\her close vote?

Comment: `strncpy(array, search, 1)` isn't going to bode well for terminating your otherwise-indeterminate `array`. May want to check the docs on how that function works.

Comment: @CoolGuy after putting a close vote, click on _close_ option below the question again and you'll see the option `vote to close` has changed to `retract close vote`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh , Ah .Thanks . I can't believe I've never seen that button when I close certain questions!

Comment: @Rizier123 I assume (s)he understands minimal required part. This question alredy has _accepted_ answer. :-)

Comment: The OP assumes the character always appears exactly 3 times. A simple fix is to read [what `strchr` returns](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strchr.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always searching from the beginning of the string. Instead, you have to start from a position after your last match.

Two changes should do the trick:

```
char *search = string;
```

and

```
search = strchr(search, 'u');
```

Comment: Why translating don't give reputation? :D

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop iteration being done on identifier `i` which iterates from `0` to `2`. But inside loop identifier `i` need to be used in such a way your `array` gets respective chars gets copied using your statement `strncpy`. This is the reason only first char being found.

You should be copying next char as `strncpy(array[i], search, 1);`. And print all the three `array` indexes separately in the loop.